# How do I count the number of objects in a numpy array about a specified threshold

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

How do I get the count of all numbers greater than a threshold number for each row in two dimensional numpy array?

For example, if I have threshold of 4 and this array...

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
 [1, 2, 3, 8, 9],
 [1, 2, 3, 5, 5]]
```

I want this output...

```
[1, 2, 2]
```

I could iterate through this but I'm guessing numpy has a more efficient way of doing this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite easy: `.sum(1)` calulate the sum row wise. `x>4` is a boolean array. When calculate `sum`, `True` is `1` and `False` is `0`.

```
In [173]:

x = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
             [1, 2, 3, 8, 9],
             [1, 2, 3, 5, 5]])
In [174]:

(x>4).sum(1)
Out[174]:
array([1, 2, 2])

In [175]:

x>4
Out[175]:
array([[False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: This works but I don't understand why.  Is (x>4) a mask?  If it is... how do you sum a mask?

Comment: No, `(x>4)` is a boolean array.